# Check if a string is inside paragraphs of a div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of strings

```
my_list = ["A simple sentence" , "Lorem Ipsum" , "Example"]
```

I want to check if any of these strings inside my list is part of the content inside paragraphs of `<div id="lead">` or `<div id="detail" >`.

So first I want to check inside each parapraph of it, if I find text I want to replace it just to change font color eg `style="color:red;"`.

I tried like this :

```
    my_list = ["A simple sentence" , "Lorem Ipsum" , "Example"]
    if ($("#lead").length) {
        $('p').each(function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < my_list.length; i++) {
                    var text =  my_list[i];
                    var result =  $(this).search(text)
                    if( result != -1){
                       // replace code? a
                       $this.text().replace(text, <p style="color:red;> text </p>)
                    }
                }
        });
   }
```

Now i dont know how to make it search in both those paragraphs? 
And should I use that way of replacing string bacuse it replace the hole p.

Lets say that this is a web page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="trunk">
         <div id="header">
            <p> ...</p>
            <p> ...</p>
         </div>
            <div id="lead"> 
               <p>Lorem Ipsum  </p>
               <p> some text ... </>
            </div>
            <div id="detail" >
               <p> What is it?</p>
               <p> Why do we use it?</p>
               <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
            </div>
         <div id="another-div">
            <p> ...</p>
            <p> ...</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Help me please!
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/2564/#&togetherjs=vwOh3P0FLf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('p').each` will search for every instance of `p` on the page, so you'll want to do something like `$('#lead p').each` to search every instance of `p` inside of `$('#lead')`.

You could also add a `data` attribute to each container div, something like `data-name="search-div"` and then you could do something like `$('[data-name="search-div"] p').each`.

For the string replace, you can do this

```
$('[data-name="search-div"] p').each(function() {
  for (var count = 0; count < my_list.length; count++) {
    var text = my_list[count];
    var str = $(this).text();
    if (str.indexOf(text) >= 0) { //This is a case-sensitive search
      $(this).html(
        $(this).html().replace(text, "<span class='red'>$&</span>")
      );
    }
  }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdLbn0vr/)

Answer (score 1):

You can search each `p` element with `each`, then create **RegExp** object for each array element and then use `replace` to find it and wrap it inside `span` element. Then you can apply style to `span` elements.

```js
var my_list = ["A simple sentence", "Lorem Ipsum", "Example"];

$("#lead, #detail").find('p').each(function() {
  for (var count = 0; count < my_list.length; count++) {
    var re = new RegExp(my_list[count], "g");
    $(this).html(function(i, el) {
      return el.replace(re, "<span class='red'>$&</span>");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trunk">
  <div id="header">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="lead">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>some text ...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="detail">
    <p>What is it?</p>
    <p>Why do we use it?</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Example text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="another-div">
    <p>A simple sentence Lorem Ipsum ...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP stated that he wanted to only change paragraphs in `#lead` and `#details` div. Maybe `$("#lead p, #detail p").each(...)` would do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmLwckb7/3/) for you.

For the HTML, I cleaned up the structure just slightly so the `<p>` and `<div>` tags are all properly closed.

```
<div id="trunk">
  <div id="header">
    <p> ...</p>
    <p> ...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="lead">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum </p>
    <p> some text ... </p>
  </div>
  <div id="detail">
    <p> What is it?</p>
    <p> Why do we use it?</p>
    <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="another-div">
    <p> ...</p>
    <p> ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the JavaScript, I made the variable naming more clear, and I also updated the search/replace to use a RegularExpression so *every* instance of each item in your list is replaced. If you'll notice, I added Lorem Ipsum twice in the HTML to demonstrate this.

```
var my_list = ["A simple sentence", "Lorem Ipsum", "Example"];
$('#lead p, #detail p').each(function() {
  var p = $(this);
  for (var i = 0; i < my_list.length; i++) {
    var haystack = p.html();
    var needle = my_list[i];
    if (haystack.split(needle).length > 1) {
      p.html(
        haystack.replace(new RegExp(needle, 'g'), 
        "<span class='red'>" + needle + "</span>")
       );
    }
  }
});
```

I also added some CSS since inline styles are generally a bad practice:

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
```